# Can a method return another method with same return type?

Tags: java, return, return-value, return-type

Here are my code blocks in my Doubly-Linked List (circular) implementation.

Can it return a method, like the return statement for addBefore method?

```
public boolean addAfter(int value, int target) {
    Node targetNode = findExact(target);
    Node temp = new Node(value);

    if(targetNode == null) {
        return false;
    } else if((targetNode.next == null)) { //prevNode is head, when list.size = 1
        temp.next = head;
        temp.prev = targetNode;
        targetNode.next = temp;
        head.prev = temp;
        size++;
        return true;
    } else if(targetNode.next == head) { //prevNode is tail,
        temp.next = targetNode.next;
        temp.prev = targetNode;
        targetNode.next = temp;
        head.prev = temp;
        size++;
        return true;
    } else { //prevNode is a node inbetween two nodes
        temp.next = targetNode.next;
        temp.prev = targetNode;
        targetNode.next = temp;
        temp.next.prev = temp;
        size++;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean addBefore(int value, int target) {
    Node targetNode = findPrev(target);
    return addAfter(value, targetNode.data);    
}
```

Comment: It's not returning another method, it's returning the value returned by the other method.  That being said, yes there's no reason you can't do that.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Got a NullPointerException, meaning there's some logic error I didn't find from addAfter, or addAfter shouldn't just be applied that way due to the nature of adding a node before its target may require a different logic. Thanks for confirming this works, like I thought, I guess I will answer to myself after I figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to state returning a value from method in case of addBefore method where you want to leverage addAfter. That bit is valid and you should look at the semantic of your underlying method addAfter and possibly findExact as to what they are returning that is leading to NPE.

It is also possible to return a method, don't think you need it here nonetheless this assumes there is a method called myMethod which takes an array of integer, the syntax will look something as below:

```
            Method myMethod;
            try {
                myMethod = TestApp.class.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", int[].class);
                myMethod.invoke(null, ar);

            } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Hope this helps